# Off-topic questions on Super User

Tags: discussion, off-topic, websites

In the Super User FAQ, the following questions are stated off-topic:

- Programming, ask on Stack Overflow.
- Servers, ask on Server Fault.
- Web design and HTML/CSS layout, and your job title is "designer", ask on Doctype.

Every time, when someone asks questions about websites (i.e. browsing), someone will say it's off topic. I can't see why. It is not about programming, nor server maintenance, nor web design.

The question is, if these questions can't be asked on Super User, then where?

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42373/what-sites-are-currently-missing-from-the-trilogy and http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/04/changes-to-stack-exchange/

Comment: If you can't see why, read the "and it is **not** about …" section of the FAQ.

Comment: Since when is a web browser not software?  If it is a question about a specific site, sure, but how about issues with browsers themselves?  If we were all machines, I'm sure this would be considered off-topic, but the common sense in us as humans should prevail.  That's what makes this site work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not on the Trilogy, as of this time, although another site may be created in the future for website questions, etc.

Remember, not every IT question in the world will belong on the SOFU trilogy.

Comment: Yeah, otherwise people would start random questions about **waffles** on fridays.

Answer (score 4):

Because:

> superuser is for computer hardware and software related questions **only**. Websites are explicitly off topic as defined by the site scope laid out in the [FAQ](https://superuser.com/faq).

I don't understand why people can't read the FAQ before asking questions.

Answer (score 3):

See the FAQ: [Where can I ask questions that aren’t Super User questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41570/where-can-i-ask-questions-that-arent-super-user-questions), keeping in mind that simply not all questions fit on one of SO, SF or SU.